# Zxing API CODE_39 throwing Java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, android, zxing, barcode-scanner, code39

I am using package com.google.zxing to create a barcode with type CODE_39
and is throwing  Java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1.I am able to get the barcode with different format(code_128,PDF_417,QRCode).Why I am getting array indexout of bond exception only for code_39? I am using zxing-2.1 version.

```
         try{
         Writer write39 = new Code39Writer(); 
         BitMatrix bb = write39.encode( "WX1222276554",CODE_39,  0,0 );  
         }catch(Throwable t){
         System.out.println(t.toString());
         e.printStackTrace()
         {
```

Comment: Post the stack trace and the exact version of ZXing that you're using.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Only this error message java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 is mentioned as a part of stack trace

Comment: A stack trace has to include at least one stack frame.  It should refer to some line of code, probably inside the ZXing library.